# A question on NAT

Tags: nat

I know ISP's use NAT to provide a home user with a public IP. If multiple devices connect to the internet using the same router all will have different private IP addresses but similar public IP address because of NAT. I wanted to know, how then, data traffic understands on which device to play, say youtube, and on which to display Gmail? My brother is using Gmail and I want to watch youtube. What actually happens?

Comment: Sorry,  home networking is explicitly off-topic here, check the [help]. You might want to read up on [source NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation).

Comment: Also, that's not necessarily accurate anyway.  ISPs don't use NAT all the time. They sometimes just route between interfaces so as to provide as straight of a path as possible and to account for the fact that a lot of protocols, that the user may be implementing, don't play nice with NAT. This way it leaves it up to the customer to NAT on their end.

Comment: That being said, the equipment an ISP gives to the end user almost certainly offers NAT/PAT capabilities, but that's not what you asked about.

Answer (score 1):

NAT stands for Network Address Translation and used to conserve public IP addresses. Standards are defined in [RFC 1631](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1631) and extended in [RFC 3022](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3022.txt).

NAT works with the router which is connected to both public(the internet service provider cable) and private(LAN) networks. Routers main job is taking packets coming from the private network to the public IP address.

The Router creates a NAT table, and lets say routers public IP address is 200.20.20.20 and private IP Address is 192.168.1.1

Your computers local-IP address is 192.168.1.2
Your brothers' computers local-IP address is 192.168.1.3

Now router creates a unique port address for your computer which is called as PAT. Also creates a SNAT table and gives you public IP address but the port numbers are same. So now your computers PAT address is 192.168.1.2:45000 and SNAT address is 200.20.20.20:45000

When you request to go youtube, the router checks the table and finds your local-IP port address. Sends the request to the ISP with public IP address + your port number. When the answer returns with the port number router know that it goes to 45000 and sends back to you.